# Symfony2: prod not found 404 = 200?

Tags: php, symfony

In the prod environment when a nonexistent URI (e.g., .../green) is requested I'd expect the custom 404 error page to be rendered.  The response header is

```
Date: Sat, 16 Nov 2013 19:11:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) PHP/5.4.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
Content-Length: 2455
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

200 OK
```

and the response is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\cache\prod\classes.php on line 1883 Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException: in G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php on line 1682 Call Stack: 0.0000 130880 1. {main}() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\web\app.php:0 0.0200 340984 2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\web\app.php:21 0.1800 2659792 3. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2249 0.1800 2661000 4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2947 0.1800 2661032 5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2818 0.1800 2661576 6. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2833 0.4900 4232624 7. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\cache\prod\classes.php:1764 0.4900 4233384 8. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\cache\prod\classes.php:1600 0.4900 4234080 9. call_user_func() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\cache\prod\classes.php:1667 0.4900 4234096 10. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\cache\prod\classes.php:1667 0.4900 4234360 11. Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->match() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\cache\prod\classes.php:1872 0.4900 4238400 12. appProdUrlMatcher->match() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\cache\prod\classes.php:1207 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /green" in G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\cache\prod\classes.php on line 1883 Call Stack: 0.0000 130880 1. {main}() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\web\app.php:0 0.0200 340984 2. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\web\app.php:21 0.1800 2659792 3. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() G:\Documents\workspace\sym\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2249
```

The more I try to understand this the more confused I get.  Documentation says that a simple `error404.html.twig` in `app\Resources\TwigBundle\views\Exception` will be rendered.  (Yes, I've cleared the prod cache - multiple times!  No entries in prod log.)  Is the documentation wrong and I really do need to create an exception handler just to show this 404 page because the response is a 200?

#### Update:

So I guess a 404 in the dev environment doesn't mean it'll be a 404 in prod.  I then attempted a simple exception handler to get a custom error page, but then no Monolog mail.  Attempts to integrate the custom handler with Monolog results in the following because the custom handler uses Twig.  No wonder my head is spinning.

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException] Circular reference detected for service "router", path: "cache_warmer -> router -> monolog.logger.router -> mana.exception.controller -> templating -> twig -> templating.helper.logout_url".
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: @WouterJ: I've edited to show the complete exception message above.  It's the response.

Comment: seems like a resource (file) can not be loaded, instead of a not found route.

Comment: @WouterJ: Guess I'm confusing a resource with a not found route.  Is the distinction here in internal (my code) request vs an external (user added) URI request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so remarkably, the error is due to an improper error404.html.twig file.  Once corrected it becomes useful.  Apologies.

Comment: How did you correct it , I have the same problem , a Soft 404 that returns 200 !

Comment: @Sekai: Sorry, but I don't recall the details. Best I can reconstruct I have a `TwigBundle\views\Exception` directory in `...app\Resources`.  In it I needed to have a properly configured template file; I do not remember what was wrong about the error404 template.  If this does not correspond to your environment I am at a loss to explain your issue.

Comment: No need to apologise, This answer was actually very helpful even with all my experience of Symfony ;)